# Mysql order by regex varchar not working correctly

Tags: mysql, regex

I`m trying to do simple order by (varchar field) query

My current implementation is:

```
SELECT id,name
FROM customer 
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

When i order them DESC i expect the list to be the same (reversed) but actually it`s not. For example this "555555555" name is at the bottom of ASC and again almost at the bottom on DESC

If i order it ASC the results are :

```
"id"    "name"
"147"   "AAAAAAA 55555"
"86"    "BBB"
"71"    "Building"
"148"   "Building 2"
"150"   "Corporation build"
"142"   "Customer 10.03.17"
"116"   "Customer new"
"131"   "Customer without templates"
"104"   "CustomerTEST"
"117"   "Customer_55 at moment"
"33"    "Ex_Name1414 project Support"
"139"   "FFF"
"126"   "GEARY Project"
"133"   "MMMMM1-1"
"127"   "NEW 14"
"134"   "NIKOI"
"135"   "nnn"
"144"   "NNN"
"138"   "NNNmmm111"
"91"    "Project 1818"
"105"   "Project GO"
"124"   "Project ZIP"
"128"   "SAN FRANCISCO Project"
"182"   "test"
"181"   "test"
"149"   "TEST 9/6"
"115"   "TEST Customer"
"178"   "test2"
"180"   "testing"
"120"   "TESTOVI"
"145"   "vvv"
"121"   "VVVV dnes22"
"132"   "VVVVV Project"
"130"   "Without Template"
"152"   " CATEST CONST "
"156"   " MOUNT CONST"
"154"   " RUDOH CONST "
"153"   " TEST CONST "
"146"   "555555555"
```

And when i try to order it DESC the result is not the same (reversed)
Actually the result is:

```
"id"    "name"
"130"   "Without Template"
"132"   "VVVVV Project"
"121"   "VVVV dnes22"
"145"   "vvv"
"120"   "TESTOVI"
"180"   "testing"
"178"   "test2"
"115"   "TEST Customer"
"149"   "TEST 9/6"
"182"   "test"
"181"   "test"
"128"   "SAN FRANCISCO Project"
"124"   "Project ZIP"
"105"   "Project GO"
"91"    "Project 1818"
"138"   "NNNmmm111"
"144"   "NNN"
"135"   "nnn"
"134"   "NIKOI"
"127"   "NEW 14"
"133"   "MMMMM1-1"
"126"   "GEARY Project"
"139"   "FFF"
"33"    "Ex_Name1414 project Support"
"117"   "Customer_55 at moment"
"104"   "CustomerTEST"
"131"   "Customer without templates"
"116"   "Customer new"
"142"   "Customer 10.03.17"
"150"   "Corporation build"
"148"   "Building 2"
"71"    "Building"
"86"    "BBB"
"147"   "AAAAAAA 55555"
"146"   "555555555"
"153"   " TEST CONST  "
"154"   " RUDOH CONST  "
"156"   " MOUNT CONST"
"152"   " CATEST CONST "
```

Comment: Try ORDER BY name + 0 DESC, name DECS as iam pretty sure you dont need to use regex here

Comment: `"555555555"` is part of the non-alpha set; it is correctly sorted.  Note that `5` > ` `.

Comment: @RaymondNijland with +0 it generates me a lot of warning from the type "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Ex_Name1414project Support' and not sorting the data at all (or for sure not correctly)

Comment: Yes those "can" show up after a `SHOW WARNINGS;`  In that case see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing more usage example data for maybe a better answer if it is still required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only changed the order of the `name` values but not of the groups (1 or 2). in case you want to flip the list completely you have to use the following query using `DESC` on both order parts (condition and column `name`):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM customer 
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2) DESC, name DESC
```

It looks like you are using the following query at the moment:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM customer 
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name DESC

-- same as
SELECT id, name
FROM customer 
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2) ASC, name DESC
```

In this case the groups are ordered `ASC` while the names are ordered `DESC`.